# Delete object from s3 bucket Rails 5 aws-sdk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm new to RoR.

I've configured my webapp to upload objects to s3 using 'aws-sdk' gem. The connection runs ok and the objects are uploaded correctly.

However, I struggle to delete those objects from Rails. I get this error:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<Error>
<Code>MethodNotAllowed</Code>
<Message>
The specified method is not allowed against this resource.
</Message>
<Method>POST</Method>
<ResourceType>OBJECT</ResourceType>
```

SONGS_CONTROLLER >

```
class SongsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @songs = Song.all
  end

  def create
    #make an object in your bucket for the upload
    file_to_upload = params[:file]
    file_name = params[:file].original_filename
    bucket = S3.bucket(S3_BUCKET.name)

    obj = bucket.object(file_name)
    #byebug

    #upload the file:
    obj.put(
      acl: "public-read",
      body: file_to_upload
      )

    #create an object for the upload
    @song = Song.new(
      url: obj.public_url,
      name: obj.key
      )

    #save the upload
    if @song.save
      redirect_to songs_path, notice: 'File successfully uploaded'
    else
      flash.now[:notice] = 'There was an error'
      render :new
    end
  end

  def delete
    @song = Song.find(params[:file])
    obj = bucket.object(@song.key)
    obj.delete
    @song.destroy
  end

end
```

INDEX.HTML.RB >

```
  <% @songs.each do |song| %>
  <ul>
    <%= link_to song.name, song.url %>
    ///
    <%= link_to 'Delete', song.url + song.name, method: :delete, data: {confirm: 'Do you want to delete this song?'} %>
  </ul>
  <% end %>
```

ROUTES >

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'songs/index'
  get 'songs/create'
  get 'songs/delete'
  root 'songs#index'
  resources :songs
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More than likely the issue that you are running into is with the permissions that are set on the `s3` bucket and not your code. You either need to change the [permissions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/UG/EditingBucketPermissions.html) on that bucket it self or you have to set up a [policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/using-iam-policies.html) that aws user that is trying trying to delete the file.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Permissions are right to upload/delete. My delete action is simply not responding.

Comment: Is there a reason that you don't define your `bucket` object like so `bucket = S3.bucket(S3_BUCKET.name)` in your delete method?

Comment: I've defined the bucket now as you've said, and changed this line:
`<%= link_to "Delete",  "songs/delete/?song=" + song.name, :confirm => 'Are you sure you want to delete ' + song.name + '?' %>`
now delete action is responding, but raises a new error:
`ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in SongsController#delete
Couldn't find Song with 'id'=`

Comment: Ok so this error is coming from the `params[:file]` is not a valid value, can you see what the value is?

Comment: ok, right, so I am not getting the object properly. `(byebug) @song = S3_BUCKET.find(params[:file]) #<Enumerator: #<struct Aws::S3::Types::Bucket name="mp3playlist", creation_date=2016-10-20 09:23:45 UTC>:find(nil)>`` I've tried several ways to call the object within the bucket, any idea? :/

Comment: I think you misunderstood my last comment, where you are doing this `@song = Song.find(params[:file])` it seems like `params[:file]` is not a valid value for the `id` like 7 or 43 so its not finding it in the database. Use byebug to figure out what the value of `params[:file]` is so you find the issue.

Comment: any progress on this?

Comment: ` bucket = S3.bucket(S3_BUCKET.name)
      obj = bucket.object(params[:song])
      obj.delete`
This is the final result that works.
I validate the answer for the right path to the solution, thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem trying to delete pictures from my bucket. 
As far as I can see, try changing the ACL to public-read-write. 
If it is just public-read it won't let you modify or delete the file.

When you delete the object, I had an issue where after saving I would save the link to the file in my database just like you. When you want to delete an object you only need the key.

The whole link looks like this:

```
//bucketname.region.amazonaws.com/folder/3bd8f451-0d6a-496b-94e9-5d53bde998ab/3.jpg
```

You can't issue the delete request using that link. You have to extract the key of that link.

```
  def delete_s3_image
    key = self.picture.split('amazonaws.com/')[1]
    S3_BUCKET.object(key).delete
  end
```

The key value will look then like this:

```
folder/3bd8f451-0d6a-496b-94e9-5d53bde998ab/3.jpg
```

I put this in a before_destroy callback.

```
before_destroy :delete_s3_image
```

I hope this helps you or anyone else that has problems deleting objects from S3.

Answer (score 0):

This is my final code for deleting objects in S3

```
def delete
    #delete song from DB
    @song = Song.find_by(params[:file])
    @song.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to songs_path, notice: 'File successfully deleted' and return }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
    #delete song from bucket
    bucket = S3.bucket(S3_BUCKET.name)
    obj = bucket.object(params[:song])
    obj.delete

  end
```